# Strange behaviour when Unmarshalling into struct in Go

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I'm developing a tool that can be implemented to simplify the process of creating simple CRUD operations/endpoints. Since my endpoints don't know what kind of struct they'll be receiving, I've created an interface that users can implement, and return an empty object to be filled.

```
type ItemFactory interface {
    GenerateEmptyItem() interface{}
}
```

And the users would implement something like:

```
type Test struct {
    TestString string `json:"testString"`
    TestInt int `json:"testInt"`
    TestBool bool `json:"testBool"`
}

func (t Test) GenerateEmptyItem() interface{} {
    return Test{}
}
```

When the Test object gets created, its type is "Test", even though the func returned an interface{}. However, as soon as I try to unmarshal some json of the same format into it, it strips it of its type, and becomes of type "map[string]interface {}".

```
item := h.ItemFactory.GenerateEmptyItem()

//Prints "Test"
fmt.Printf("%T\n", item)

fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(item))

err := ConvertRequestBodyIntoObject(r, &item)
if err != nil {...}

//Prints "map[string]interface {}"
fmt.Printf("%T\n", item)
```

Func that unmarshalls item:

```
func ConvertRequestBodyIntoObject(request *http.Request, object interface{}) error {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Unmarshal body into request object
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, object)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this happens, or how I can work around it?

Thanks

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question lacks an example showing this behavior so I'm just guessing this is what is happening.

```
func Generate() interface{} {
    return Test{}
}

func GeneratePointer() interface{} {
    return &Test{}
}

func main() {

    vi := Generate()
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{}`), &vi)
    fmt.Printf("Generate Type: %T\n", vi)

    vp := GeneratePointer()
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{}`), vp)
    fmt.Printf("GenerateP Type: %T\n", vp)
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Generate Type: map[string]interface {}
GenerateP Type: *main.Test
```

I suggest you return a pointer in `GenerateEmptyItem()` instead of the actual struct value which is demonstrated in the `GenerateP()` example.

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/HRyj9POZcFg)

Comment: I can see you already put the example code. Still, the answer remains - return a pointer to your struct from the factory.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, this solved the issue. Why is it, that it behaves like that when it's not a pointer?

Comment: @robbieperry22 it can be a little confusing, but think of it this way: when you return something as an interface, it's basically "wrapped" in the interface - the interface value *contains* the real value. So if you take a pointer to a real value, then wrap it in an interface, you get the expected behavior. If you take a real value, wrap it in an interface, then take a pointer to that, you've now got a pointer to a *wrapper containing a value* instead of a pointer to a value.